# AngularJS: Event callback doesn't fire on google maps native map marker

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3, angularjs, infobox

I've forked AngularUI's uiMap directive in order to swap *InfoWindow* for *InfoBox* and to add *MarkerClusters*. I've made some extensive updates to uiMap -> icMap; most notably I moved directive logic out of the controllers, making uiMap the "master" directive). I've got almost everything working, except that clicking a native MapMarker doesn't open the infobox.

I *think* the reason is that I'm not properly binding the click event to the native MapMarker (*ic-map.js:163*).

Before I re-organised uiMap I had simply added a `icMapInfoBox` directive in *map.js*. Its *open* event was registered/triggered by:

```
ui-event="{'map-click':'openMarkerInfo(marker)'}"
```

which called *openMarkerInfo()* defined in its controller (copy/paste from my repo: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jshado1/5422931)).

However, now when I click a native MapMarker, nothing happens and I get no errors in the console (but all other events still fire properly).

**Original [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ESYiktkcYyQ1ztVylGqJ?p=preview)**
**Simplified [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1VWU6T3botHVvV6ExwdO?p=preview)** (removed MarkerClusters)
In both plunks, the problem probably lies in ic-map.js (first file in the list)

*map.json* is a data file
*angular.js*, *angular-ui.js*, and *infobox.js* are lib files

**Edit** I noticed that `InfoBox.map` is `undefined`; I'm guessing that has something to do with the problem.

**Edit** The undefined InfoBox.map property was part of the problem: The manual call to *InfoBox.open* on *ic-map.js:189* works (template isn't being compiled, but that's a different problem), but the click event still doesn't trigger *InfoBox.open*. Also the template is not getting included.

SOLVED: I had been treating `marker` a DOM object instead of just a js object. Will post solution soon.

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle with all files.

Comment: @tschiela, I already provided a Plunkr with all files (it's linked at the bottom of the question). Plunkr seems a little slow today, so it takes a few seconds to load.

Comment: oh sorry i slipped that link. thx

Comment: @tschiela, np. I'll bold it so it's more noticeable.

Comment: that is to many code to overview. takes some time to get an overview. may you can break down the code and provide a such smaller plunkr. 

Often the problem is the asynchronous way of JavaScript. Events would be bindet to markers, but the markers not loaded at these moment. So check all callbacks. Also i get many errors in the chrome web developer console. Fix them first

Comment: @tschiela, if you're referring to the numerous `Uncaught Error: QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22` errors, I think those are from Plunker, not me. Also, I took out code for MarkerClusterer (updated my question with a new link), but beyond that, I think everything else is required to adequately simulate my environment. I don't think it's a problem caused by asynchronicity—that should cause an `undefined` error, no? I think the event binding should occur in addMarkers() of _ic-map.js:157_ (called on line 185).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mamx5EXtHxSo4aqMSZUd

1. *Original > ic-map.js:156* My event listener should have been bound with `google.maps.event.addListener()` (see *Working Example > ic-map.js:154-156*).
2. Also, it was too much trouble to use templates, so I added 2 divs as children of `div#map` (see *Working Example > index.html:41-42*). Due to how inheritence and shared models work, all of the directives **MUST** be on the same DOM element (because no-one can look down, only up). This was necessary for moving the directive logic out of the [controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) (as was the implementation from AngularUI). In my implementation, the model is shared across the icMaps* directives within the directives (and [directive controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject)).
3. Difference of `marker`:

   - *uiMapMarker*, `marker` is attached to a DOM object: `ng-repeat="marker in markers"`
   - *icMapMarkers*, `marker` is just a js object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add jQuery as a dependency.

Undocumented jQuery dependency for uiMap

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/552

Comment: Thank you, but that was not the problem.